# hand off management in wireless LAN

Tags: wireless

how does hand off take place in wireless LAN.I mean hand off form wireless LAN to gprs and from gprs to wireless lan.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, in this scenario no hand off on network layer. Hand of handled by application. Old connections close/die and new connection must be established by application.

Comment: Sorry but hand off does occur when mobile station moves form wlan to gprs or form gprs to wlan

Comment: It depend on how we define "hand off". To make hand of on network level (IP) device must keep IP address. It possible in tunnel, but not in base network.

Comment: how does it occur in tunneling?

Comment: Build IP tunnel from client to server side. (for ex. OpenVPN) When clent switch from one ISP (wlan) to other (mobile), client IP recieved from ISP changed, tunnel reestablished and IP inside tunnel keept unchanged.

Openvpn has special option to keep tunnel interface UP when reconnecting. So from application point of view it just loss of packets.